# Как отправить логин и пароль на сервис по https?

Tags: c#, https

Пытаюсь обратиться к веб сервису получение с сайта http://zakupki.gov.ru
Пробовал так, но не получается.

```
webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy cashePol = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
webRequest.CachePolicy = cashePol;
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("qwerty", "qwerty");
webRequest.Credentials = credentials;
//2. Ввести данные к отправке и ковертировать их в массив байтов
encodingUTF8 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
byteArray = encodingUTF8.GetBytes(postData);
```

Comment: почему думаешь, что не получается?

Comment: От сервиса не приходит ни какого ответа получаю только 500 ошибку.

Comment: 500 это как раз ответ от сервера, говорящий что ошибка произошла на сервере

Comment: т.е. вполне возможна такая ошибка из-за не корректного логина/пароля?

Comment: вряд ли. Возможно что-то случилось на сервере